# Check Moodle's hashed password

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, moodle

**Moodle** saves hashed passwords in the user table in this the format:

> If the stored password is:
>
> `$2y$10$UB6vKrpw227eqVXj2PiPou9c0eRtxsdU02fo9.wc3VtsA2FI.gS6a`
>   then:
>   `$2y$` = the id of the hashing algorithm used (crypt_blowfish), enclosed in dollar signs.
>   `10$` = the cost of using that algorithm (two digits) followed by a dollar sign.
>   `UB6vKrpw227eqVXj2PiPou` = randomly generated secure salt (22 characters).
>   `9c0eRtxsdU02fo9.wc3VtsA2FI.gS6a` = the hash (31 characters).

I have the plain password in text. I can't figure out how to check it with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply done using `bcrypt`:

```
pip install bcrypt
```

Then it is just a matter of calling the `checkpw()` function:

```
import bcrypt

hashed = b'$2y$10$UB6vKrpw227eqVXj2PiPou9c0eRtxsdU02fo9.wc3VtsA2FI.gS6a'

password = input('Enter password:').encode()
if bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed):
    print('Correct password entered!')
else:
    print('Password is wrong!')
```

Note that bcrypt is working with bytes and not strings, which is why the user input must be run through `.encode()`.

Comment: Isn't it ```pip install py-bcrypt``` and also it seems like the `hashed` is static.

Comment: and also by running the code I'm getting the error ```ValueError: Invalid hashed_password salt```

Comment: @sphoenix No, it should be `pip install bcrypt`, according to https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/ However, I haven't tried since I installed it using anaconda. Strange that you get that error. It works fine for me. Which python verison and which bcrypt versions (`bcrypt.__version__`) are you using?

Comment: @sphoenix And what do you mean by "the `hashed` is static"? It is a `bytes` object, most likely you would get it from looking up the value with the user name as key.

Comment: ```python 3.5.2, bcrypt: 3.1.4```

Comment: @sphoenix And you get that error when you copy-paste the code that I have provided? That's odd, since it seems to work just as it should on my system. However, since we don't know the initial password, it is hard to see if it is correctly evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, I copied and pasted and got the error! Weird!

Comment: Say, we have many passwords. Can we use your method for all of the passwords?

Comment: @sphoenix Each user is likely to have only one password, so typically you store each hashed password in a lookup table, and use the user name (or another type of identification e.g. email address) as key to the table. That is, when you know what user that wants to login you will have only one password to test against.